# Enable CKEditor4 inline on span and other inline tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, contenteditable, inline-editing

I'd like to know if it's possible and how to enable the CKEditor4 inline/contenteditable editing feature on `<span>` and other inline elements. This is something which I cannot find in the official docs.

With this markup:

```
<span id="editable" contenteditable="true"></span>
```

And either the standard configuration (AutoInline enabled) or this configuration:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline('editable'); // ID of the element to edit
</script>
```

An error is reported: `The specified element mode is not supported on element: "span".`
The same error is reported for `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hack way to allow support for un supported tags:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.span = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.a = 1
```

Win.

Comment: Nice, it works although it splits the span into two if you try to paste :\

Comment: It is a sort of a workaround, however you'll get far with it as a lot of CKE4 internals will start to fall down. The general take-away is that we're not going to support creating editor on an inline element, as there is a problem that we're unable to get around for IE11 (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8988348/).

Answer (score 3):

Nope. It is not possible to create editor on inline elements. [Here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/dtd.js#L236) you can find list of accepted names.

However, I checked that after modifying that list I was able to initialize editor on `strong` element and it even works... Unless you paste or do other unsupported action :).

Comment: No. Only `strong`, but the result will be the same or worse (e.g. for link).