# TD as CKEditor inline instance

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is it possible to make content of TD tag editable with CKEditor inline?

I wrote code:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    this content IS editable
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true"> not IS NOT editable </td>
        <td contenteditable="true"> not IS NOT editable </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/martinba/JBFmd/1/

I cant find if it is a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Check my answer for [Enable CKEditor4 inline on span and other inline tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575036/enable-ckeditor4-inline-on-span-and-other-inline-tags/14579281#14579281). This is the same case - CKEditor does not support initializing it on `td`. You can try to hack editor just like BenO did in this answer [Enable CKEditor4 inline on span and other inline tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575036/enable-ckeditor4-inline-on-span-and-other-inline-tags/15014459#15014459) but the result is unpredictable.