# Using CKEditor with angular's partial view

Tags: symfony, angularjs, ckeditor, angularjs-directive

I am currently using CKEditor as my WYSIWYG editor for the text on my site. And I just ran into a problem of using this editor with angular's partial views. The views are hidden with ng-hide and ng-show.

When I am outside of my current partial view the editor works fine. Meaning the tool bar pops up, the buttons on the tool bar work, and the text is editable as well.

However when I am in my partial view the popup still comes up, but the text is not editable, and the buttons are disabled.

This is my current code to bring up the editor

```
plunker.directive('ckEditor', function($http, $timeout) {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(elm[0]);

      if (!ngModel) return;

      ck.on('pasteState', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());

        });
      });

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

So my question is has anyone gotten CKEditor to work with partial views? If so how did you do it?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or plnkr? Are you using `ngView` or `ngInclude` for your partial?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any example, so it's hard to tell. There may be few reasons,

1. check if the element type is supported by CKEditor - if not you'll have to hack CKEditor config by copying some settings from `div`
2. ensure your element has `contenteditable='true'`
3. ensure you are manually instrumenting CKEditor to provide editor for your partials.

you may also want to read this:
[Enable CKEditor4 inline on span and other inline tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575036/enable-ckeditor4-inline-on-span-and-other-inline-tags)
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-editable